Rolling Window Averages
I'll try to keep this brief.  I have a hyper table for stock data called tick_data.  I then create a continuous aggregation of 5 seconds of this data. With this I'm trying to create 1 minute calculations but more granular than having a regular 1 minute aggregation.  For instance, every 5 seconds I want to keep track of what the 1 minute window of times average volume is.  I want this to be able to go back thousands of windows into the past.
So instead of only calculating avg minute volumes in the defined time slots of say 1:10:00 to 1:11:00.  I want to have a new calculation for 1:10:00 to 1:11:00, then 1:10:05 to 1:11:05, 1:10:10 to 1:11:10, etc.
I tried creating a trigger function off of the 5 second aggregation to keep a new hyper table of the rolling 1 minute volumes that I would do a new aggregation on but got an error about creating a function.
I'm sure there is probably something with a window function.  I'm very new with back-end development. It seems that after you create an aggregation you're limited on what you can do with the aggregation data.  I could try something directly on the tick_data but was trying to reduce computation since that could be thousands of computations a second potentially.  Maybe the optimizations of Timescale make that not matter I do not know.  Looking for advice. Thank you, here are my table creations I have so far.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tick_data (
        timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
        symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
        price FLOAT NOT NULL,
        size INTEGER NOT NULL,
        tick_type TEXT,
        condition TEXT,
        session TEXT,
        dollars FLOAT

SELECT create_hypertable(
    'tick_data', 
    'timestamp', 
    partitioning_column => 'symbol',  
    number_partitions => 25,            
    chunk_time_interval => INTERVAL '1 day',
    if_not_exists => TRUE

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS agg_5s
    WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
    SELECT
        time_bucket('5 seconds', timestamp) AS bucket_timestamp,
        symbol,
        session,
        -- OHLC aggregations
        first(price, timestamp) AS open_price,
        last(price, timestamp) AS close_price,
        max(price) AS high_price,
        min(price) AS low_price,
        -- Total Volume and Tick Aggregations
        sum(size) AS total_volume,
        count(*) AS total_ticks,
        sum(dollars) AS total_dollars,
        -- Aggregations Based on `tick_type`
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'up' THEN size ELSE 0 END) AS up_volume,
        count(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'up' THEN 1 END) AS up_ticks,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'up' THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS up_dollars,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'down' THEN size ELSE 0 END) AS down_volume,
        count(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'down' THEN 1 END) AS down_ticks,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'down' THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS down_dollars,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'side' THEN size ELSE 0 END) AS side_volume,
        count(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'side' THEN 1 END) AS side_ticks,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'side' THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS side_dollars
    FROM
        tick_data
    GROUP BY
        bucket_timestamp, symbol, session;

EDIT: This post seems to be doing pretty much the same kind of thing that I want to do but the syntax is screwing me up with my lack of understanding back end.  Is it possible to calculate a cumulative sum or moving average with a TimescaleDB continuous aggregate?.  So I probably need a SELECT AS that then does sum(over last12) where last12 is the preceding minute for 12, 5 second periods in a minute and then... This is where I'm really lost as then how do I keep the rolling average OF those last12 bucket values over the last X amount of buckets...
EDIT 2: OOOk hold on I am starting to understand that I need to do a stats agg here but I don't know the full syntax of this.  I'm not sure if I can do this with a calculated number or not but like
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS agg_5s
    WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
    SELECT
        time_bucket('5 seconds', timestamp) AS bucket_timestamp,
        symbol,
        session,
        first(price, timestamp) AS open_price,
        last(price, timestamp) AS close_price,
        max(price) AS high_price,
        min(price) AS low_price,
        sum(size) AS total_volume,
        count(*) AS total_ticks,
        sum(dollars) AS total_dollars,
        -- Aggregations Based on `tick_type`
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'up' THEN size ELSE 0 END) AS up_volume,
        count(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'up' THEN 1 END) AS up_ticks,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'up' THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS up_dollars,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'down' THEN size ELSE 0 END) AS down_volume,
        count(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'down' THEN 1 END) AS down_ticks,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'down' THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS down_dollars,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'side' THEN size ELSE 0 END) AS side_volume,
        count(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'side' THEN 1 END) AS side_ticks,
        sum(CASE WHEN tick_type = 'side' THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS side_dollars,
        stats_agg(total_volume)
    FROM
        tick_data
    GROUP BY
        bucket_timestamp, symbol, session;

And then I need to reference this in a window function query on the aggregated data. Questions now are how do I use the stats_agg on more than one variable in the aggregated data as eventually I would like to add more than just the total volume to this. I also am quite confused on the rolling window function and how the math works on that.

Conisider using FILTER instead of CASE expressions: e.g., SUM(size) FILTER (WHERE tick_type = 'up') and COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE tick_type = 'up'). Separating the what and when concerns can improve readability.

Ok thank you.  I will look into improving that.   Do you happen to have any insight on the stats_agg stuff?  This setup ended up erroring as it said "total_volume" did not exist.  I guess I need to stats_agg with size and then reference that in the window function.  I ended up getting stuck because it turns out Timescale toolkit isn't on windows so I just spend like 3 hours converting everything over to Docker and haven't made much progress on the query.

I haven't used Timescale; however, I've taken a brief look at the documentation. Your assessment regarding total_volume seems to be correct. From the docs, it looks like your should do something like stats_agg(size) AS size_stats and then use the accessor functions; e.g., average(size_stats), sum(size_stats), etc.

For stats_agg check the rolling() function. https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/blob/main/docs/rolling_average_api_working.md
Also check if candlestick_agg can make the OHLCV part.

Thank you.  Yes just yesterday I had started to look into the rolling function.  I've just never been good at back end.  I dunno I guess I'm just not smart enough to understand the queries or something it confuses me exactly what data we are able to get and how to interact with them.  Rolling is definitely correct.  I just don't fully understand the syntax yet. I've been watching Timescale videos and have just come to the conclusion this is one of those topics I'm going to need to slow down on and see if I can fully conceptualize first.
